# OSGeo4W shell does not accept cs2cs command if typed, only if coppied from a website

Tags: osgeo4w, cs2cs

I tried to type in a cs2cs command and OSGeo4W shell did not accept it. When I pasted it from the text on the web it did accept it (see screenshot - command executed is the one pasted and command resulting with an error is the one typed in). suggestions?

[image: Command resulting with an error is the one typed in as opposed to pasted[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js6dv.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You have written ESPG instead of EPSG.

Comment: It is a perfect answer but the question is worth closing.

Comment: BTW it is worth remembering that EPSG stands for European Petroleum Survey Group. I've eventually memorized the full name because I used to make the same mistake frequently.